# How to run Python Script on powerBI

Tags: python, powerbi

I have a problem with the python scripting to run on Power BI. 
Now I'm using Anaconda with the base(root) environment. The Power BI Desktop automatically found the Python home directories but it does not work.

I would like to use K mean classification so I code it on python and want to present the plot on Power BI.

The version of python that I'm using is 3.7, I also find the method on google but none of them work (add into PATH, reinstall,....)

```py
Feedback Type:
Frown (Error)

Product Version:
2.73.5586.561 (19.09) (x64)

Error Message:
Python script error.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\USERS\TJTEC\ANACONDA3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
  File "C:\USERS\TJTEC\ANACONDA3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\multiarray.py", line 14, in <module>
    from . import overrides
  File "C:\USERS\TJTEC\ANACONDA3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\overrides.py", line 7, in <module>
    from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import (
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PythonScriptWrapper.PY", line 2, in <module>
    import os, uuid, matplotlib
  File "C:\USERS\TJTEC\ANACONDA3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 138, in <module>
    from . import cbook, rcsetup
  File "C:\USERS\TJTEC\ANACONDA3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "C:\USERS\TJTEC\ANACONDA3\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "C:\USERS\TJTEC\ANACONDA3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 47, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError:
```

How to solve this problem? Thank all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the method. Besides anaconda, I have not installed any original python package separately. Then, I install the python 3.7.5 on the main site python.org and using `pip install package` for any desired packages. The PowerBI again automatically detects the new one and add it to the main directory for running the script.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question you've been asking above.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple situations to handle these issues.

```
1. Did you downloaded the latest Anaconda version from below link: 
   https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/#download-section
2. Did you check these paths were added to the system Environmental path?
   C:\Users\<myusername>\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\Scripts\
   C:\Users\<myusername>\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\Library\
   C:\Users\<myusername>\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\Library\bin\
   C:\Users\<myusername>\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin\
3. Uninstall numpy and install numpy via pip
4. Update to latest Pycharm
```

Comment: why do I need to an the paths? why is pycharm required to run python

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Anaconda, it needs to be activated before you can use it. Simply open the *Anaconda Prompt* or run *conda activate* on the cmd prompt. Then **start PBIDesktop from within the activated environment** like:

```
(base) C:\> "Program Files\Microsoft Power BI Desktop\bin\PBIDesktop.exe"
```

On Windows 10 you have to look for the PBIDesktop.exe in C:\Program Files\WindowsApps. Make sure the Python home directory (Anaconda3) has been added to the PBIDesktop global options in the *Python scripting* section too.