# PowerBi error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'seaborn'

Tags: python-3.x, powerbi, seaborn

I am trying to run the test following code in PowerBI:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = sns.load_dataset('iris')
sns.jointplot(x=df["sepal_length"], y=df["sepal_width"], kind='hex')

plt.show()
```

However, I am getting the following error:

[image]

I successfully executed this code in spyder with no issues. Troubleshooting performed:

- conda update --all
- conda uninstall seaborn
- conda install seaborn

However, there was no change in the error message. Does anyone have any suggestions on what steps should be taken next?

Comment: My guess is PowerBI is not pointing to the correct installation of python. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-python-scripts

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58686991/7758804

Comment: I have changed the Python Home Directory, but that made things worse. Any modification gave the message "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'"