# Pass variable value to a Python script via Power BI

Tags: python, powerbi

I want to create a simple dataframe with a Python script in *Power BI*.

However, I would like to control the variable `count` via Power BI with a GUI-input control like slider or using dropdown or something similar.

#### Code

Here is a sample code which I want to execute:

```py
import pandas as pd

count = 2  # this variable should be set from outside via Power BI

test_list = ['hello world'] * count

df = pd.DataFrame(test_list, columns=['test'])
```

However, I don't want to hard-code `count` (like in the sample code above).

Rather I want to control it via e.g. a slider like this:

[image: slider GUI control]

Is something like this possible in the combination of Power BI and Python?

Answer (score -2):

It depends on the purpose of your Python script.

You can either pass arguments to "Run Python Scripts" or to "Power BI Queries".

#### Passing command-line arguments

Let's suppose you run a Python script like explained in
[Run Python Scripts in Power BI Desktop - Power BI | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-python-scripts) or [How to run Python Script on powerBI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58686991/how-to-run-python-script-on-powerbi)

Since the script is called like a regular program from a command-line there can also be passed command-line arguments to the script. Those arguments can then interpreted by your Python script as parameters.

See also:

- Microsoft Power BI Community: [Solved: Can I call a function from a personal Python Scrip...](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Can-I-call-a-function-from-a-personal-Python-Scripit-in-Power-BI/td-p/813584)

#### Passing Query parameters

You can also pass query-parameters (entered by the user in a GUI-control like dropdown list) to your Python script.
Those query-parameters which have been defined before in Power BI can then be read within Python using [`Text.From(param1)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/text-from).

See also:

- Ben's Blog: [Power BI pass parameter value to python script](https://datakuity.com/2021/01/05/power-bi-pass-parameter-value-to-python-script/)
- Microsoft Power BI Community: [Passing parameters from Power BI to Python script ...](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Passing-parameters-from-Power-BI-to-Python-script-for-the-first/td-p/1056280)